# Probability of flipping a coin an exact number of times

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-distribution

A biased coin flips heads with probability 4/9 and tails with probability 5/9. The coin is flipped 90 times. What is the probability that heads is flipped exactly 40 times?

I believe this question requires the utilisation of the binomial distribution in which:

$Pr(H) = \frac{4}{9}$

$Pr(T) = \frac{5}{9}$

$n = 90$

$k = 40$

$Pr(X = 40) = {90\choose 40}(\frac{4}{9})^{40}  (1 - \frac{4}{9}) ^{90-40} =
{90\choose 40}  (\frac{4}{9})^{40} (\frac{5}{9}) ^{50}$

is approximately 0.084

Am I going abouts this correctly? Not feeling too confident

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Nr of Heads is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(90, 4/9)$ and the formula for the PMF of this dist'n gives $P(X = 40) = {90 \choose 40}(\frac 4 9)^{40}(\frac 5 9)^{50}.$ In R, `dbinom(39:42, 90, 4/9)` returns values 0.08273508, **0.08438978,** 0.08233150, and 0.07684273. The **second** of these is $P(X=40),$ which is also the mode of this particular binomial distribution. // So the most likely outcome is to get 40 Heads, but that exact result does not have a particularly large probability. // Your formula is correct and your numerical answer is correct to three places.

Answer (score 1):

The standard deviation for this is $$\sqrt{np(1-p)} = \sqrt{90\cdot \frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{5}{9}} = 4.714$$

Roughly $2/3$ of the outcomes for the number of heads would be between about $35$ and $45$. That's $11$ outcomes each with a probability of less than $0.09$ to ensure the total is less than $1$. So your answer of $.084$ is right in the ball park.